# Stashing images from a Matrix field grabs only the image from the last entry on the page

Tags: channel-entries, matrix, stash

Inside of my entries loop I have a Matrix field called `{blog_images}` where the user can store up to 10 images. The user then determines where these images should appear in the content area (`{blog_post_content}`) using shortcodes like this:

```
<p>First paragraph is here.</p>
{image_1}
<p>Second paragraph is here.</p>
{image_2}
<p>…</p>
```

Currently I'm using Stash to loop through the Matrix images and store them for insertion into `{blog_post_content}`. Strange thing is if I have 10 entries appear on the page, every entry is showing only the image from the LAST entry instead of its own image.

Here is my existing code:

```
{blog_images}
    {exp:stash:set type="snippet" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
        {stash:image_{row_count}}
            <figure class="{placement} {size}">
                {exp:ce_img:pair src="{image}" width="{size}" allow_scale_larger="no" cache_dir="images/blog" hide_relative_path="yes" parse="inward"}
                    <img src="/assets/images/css/holder.png" width="{width}" height="{height}" data-src="{made}" alt="{alt_text}">
                {/exp:ce_img:pair}
                {if caption}
                    <figcaption>
                        {caption}
                    </figcaption>
                {/if}
            </figure>
        {/stash:image_{row_count}}
    {/exp:stash:set}
{/blog_images}
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {blog_post_content}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the latest version of Stash (as of writing 2.3.9)? Your code should work but a few versions back there was a bug in `{exp:stash:parse}` which meant that `parse_vars` didn't get run under certain circumstances.

https://github.com/croxton/Stash

EDIT: just realised you've left off the wrapping channel entries tag which would have made it clear why your code can't possibly work unless limit='1'. You are overwriting the value of {image_x} with each iteration of the channel entries tag. The solution is to use a list with the entry id as a context. I will update this answer with sample code shortly.

EDIT2: use context and the @ pointer to point to the static context:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
{blog_images}
    {exp:stash:set type="snippet" context="{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
        {stash:image_{row_count}}
            <figure class="{placement} {size}">
                {exp:ce_img:pair src="{image}" width="{size}" allow_scale_larger="no" cache_dir="images/blog" hide_relative_path="yes" parse="inward"}
                    <img src="/assets/images/css/holder.png" width="{width}" height="{height}" data-src="{made}" alt="{alt_text}">
                {/exp:ce_img:pair}
                {if caption}
                    <figcaption>
                        {caption}
                    </figcaption>
                {/if}
            </figure>
        {/stash:image_{row_count}}
    {/exp:stash:set}
{/blog_images}
{exp:stash:parse process="end" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:stash:context name="{entry_id}"}
    {blog_post_content}
{/exp:stash:parse}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Only caveat is that you'll need to refer to the images like this in the {blog_post_content} field:

`{@:image_1}`, `{@:image_2}`, etc

Comment: Yeah, that's the version I'm using…

Answer (score 2):

Your exp:stash:set is inside a channel entries loop?  I think you might be better off using stash:set_list in place of stash:set. stash:set is often used to surround an entries loop, whereas stash:set_list is used inside the loop, stashing elements within the loop into a list (hence the name).   I think set_list may be more consistent with what you're looking to do.

Comment: If I use a list how do I then replace the `{image_#}` shortcodes inside the `{blog_post_content}`?

Comment: Maybe append the entry ID in there with the row ID to make each one unique and specific to each entry stashed?  set_list works pretty mush the same way as set, but it loops and stores a list (it's basically its own entries loop) rather than a single entry or a block of entries.